# Google Maps JavaScript API, finding Euler tour

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-maps, routes

I'm trying to create a script for google maps, which calculates an optimal (or near-optimal) tour which goes through all streets in a given area. I have come up with a following idea:

1) I generate random points within a given polygon (as much as it is possible)
2) I use DirectionsService.route() to find a optimal way with the random points from 1) set as waypoints.

This algorithm, assuming i have enough waypoints should be quite okay. The problem is, that directionsService allows up to 8 waypoints which is quite too strict limit for my needs (I would need about few 100 waypoints for this algorithm to work ok. Even with bussiness licence the upper  limit is 23 waypoints per request, which is still not good.

Maybey someone has an idea of some walk around those limits, or a better way to solve my problem?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a batch and split the waypoints and use many different geocode. There is the tsp javascript solver from Gebweb. I think up to 50 isn't a problem at all.